# Laravel new storage log permissions

Tags: php, laravel, logging, storage

I have a problem with much discussed storage permission issues. I have set permissive permissions currently for the time being, and will change them later, but the issue is not there.

Since I'm running Apache, I have chowned complete directory on `www-data`. It's location is in `/var/www/html/*` folder.

The issue I'm having is that when new day comes, a new log is created with `root` owner, thus Apache is no longer able to write to that file.

How can I track down who is originator for creating log files? How can I make `www-data` a default user which is creating logs?

Comment: Whenever I have this issue it usually revolves around the entire bootstrap/cache folder and not the log file itself, have you tried setting the permissions recursively on that folder?

Comment: Yeah, but recursive works on existing files, not ones which are yet to be created